# IllegalAccessException on protected class member while parsing Excel 2007 file using Apache POI library on AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, apache-poi

I am trying to parse excel 2007 (.xlsx) file using Apache POI library on Google AppEngine but while doing that I am getting an exception (see below).

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime$21 can not access a member of  class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet with modifiers "protected"
```

So I checked with Apache POI team, but they claim that its an AppEngine issue. I am not sure what is the right place for AppEngine questions, but I know lot of appengine developers monitor Stackoverflow. So posting this question here.

Bug filed for Apache POI team : https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55665

This bug has a sample maven project, and instructions to reproduce it. 
I am not sure how to attach this zip file here.

If any one knows how to fix this then let me know, or right place to file bug.

The key part of the stacktrace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime$21 can not access a member of  class org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet with modifiers "protected"
at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:105)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime$22.run(Runtime.java:488)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkAccess(Runtime.java:485)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.checkAccess(Runtime.java:479)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance_(Runtime.java:123)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInstance(Runtime.java:135)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:60)
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue. I think this is only an issue with the development server. Admittedly, this doesn't fully answer your question but I guess the situation at least isn't as bas as you'd think. To get around the issue I've been developing my POI code in a standard Java project (using dummy data) and then copying it into the App Engine project.

I've logged the issue with Google: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11752

If you're interested, in the process of logging the issue, I created a sample project which is also available on App Engine (which works as it's running in the production environment).

- Sample project: https://bitbucket.org/bronze/jakarta-poi-issue
- App running on production environment: http://bronze-gae-poi-issue.appspot.com/